# Angular 2 Multi Step Form progress bar with

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, zurb-foundation-6, angular2-formbuilder

I am trying to make a flow which is very similar to (http://plnkr.co/edit/M03tYgtfqNH09U4x5pHC?p=preview)
but with angular2. I have the flows ready although not taking the state or data into consideration, but I am more interested the the progress bar and I am totally lost as to where to start for the progress bar and how to approach the same. I would really appreciate any help in this.
Here is the basic outline of the component i have which is static does not do anything atm.

```
`import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {ManualDemographics} from '../../manual-demographics';

@Component({
  selector: 'progress-wizard',
  providers: [ ],
  styleUrls: [ './multistep-progress-wizard.style.scss' ],
  templateUrl: './multistep-progress-wizard.template.html'
})

export class ProgressWizard {
  constructor(
    private zone: NgZone,
    private router: Router){}
}
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path:'manualDemographics', component: ManualDemographics}
];`
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: in your attached plunker working with angular1 not with angular2, for that you have to use angular2's routing and all components as well

Comment: @PardeepJain Yes i understand it was with Angular 1 , sorry if i was not clear but I am looking for something w=very similar but in angular 2

Comment: haha i get your point but i think you have not tried so far in angular2, its not possible for someone here to cook same for you, ask if any problem in your code, good luck

Comment: @PardeepJain very unfortunately I am a newbie trying to get my head around Angular2 and I have to complete the task since it is a new project my company took on. I am trying on my end too and will post updates as I go :)

Comment: ohh thats sounds cool ;) good luck :p

Answer (score 0):

I think Material UI's Stepper will do exactly what you need and is very simple to implement:-

https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

You should only have to import the MatStepperModule module too, so not much overhead.